# Python code failing to execute Json.Dump after upgrading from 2.7 to 3.10

Tags: python, json, uipath

To preface, this is not my code and am just trying to resolve it. I am not accustomed to Python (just have been introduced with it recently with this project)

We run python scripts via UiPath. We upgraded the version of all python dependencies to Py3.10 which meant I had to convert the scripts using 2to3 as well, I've pinpointed the issue but I don't have any idea why this part of the script would fail.

Debugging technique used - slip ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW in between lines of the script.

Here's the part of the code that was no longer able to show the message box (which I assumed is where this problematic). Line formatted as bold.

```
dObj = open(param_response_result_file)
ogdata = json.load(dObj)
ogdata['results']['fields'] = field_value_dictionary
with open(param_response_result_file, 'w+') as outfile:
    **json.dump(ogdata, outfile)**
    outfile.write("\n")
```

What can be the root causes for this line to fail? I've checked param_response_result_file and it contains the correct values, what more can I check to trace why this json.dump is failing?

Thank you

- EDIT I found the exception being thrown:

> Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable

How do I resolve this? I am aware that there has been variable changes between Py 2 to 3 upgrade with json instantiations, but how do I get it to pass the correct variable?

Comment: there's this much simpler and more commonly used debugging technique which is basically `print("I'm here")`, also it's not clear what you mean by _failing to execute_, does it raise an error? if so what was there more to debug even, just see the error, it tells you the line and the cause

Comment: First off, you're opening `param_response_result_file` for reading on the first line, not closing it, then attempting to open it again for reading and writing on the fourth line. However, debugging would be much easier if you can provide a [mre] and the [*full text* of any errors or tracebacks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146).

Comment: hard thing about this one is we don't have VS in the test machine that I'm testing this on - two methods I use is just running it via CMD "python [filename]" and via UiPath which doesn't help as well (it just tells me a super vague error exception "Pipeline is broken".

Comment: Running via CMD should give you a proper traceback, as long as you're not catching it in a `try/except` block.

Comment: Ran it via CMD and it does not throw any errors. Does this mean there is something wrong with the input files being loaded?

Comment: Change your first line into a `with open(...` block and see if that clears things up. Alternatively, after the second line, put in `dObj.close()`.

Comment: @MattDMo I tried changing it to with open(dObj = open(param_response_result_file)): but that did not work, what should be the correct expression?

Comment: It would be `with open(param_response_result_file) as dObj:`, then the next line should be indented below it. I have a question, though - why are you opening a file, reading it, then opening *the same file* again and writing its original data to it?

Comment: I wheezed at the way you worded at how this script works. Is that really what's happening here? would the whole code help you understand this more? This is just a snippet of what  the script is

Comment: @MattDMo but if that's the case, shouldn't the json.dump work and just return everything as if nothing happened? what more can cause the json.dump to throw an exception?

Comment: Anything about formatting? or variable type that is being passed? What do you think?

Comment: hi @MattDMo, i think I found the issue -

This is being thrown - "Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable"

How do i correctly convert it so that this exception does not get thrown?

Comment: @J.Carrillo yes, please post a [mre] of your script. We should be able to paste a single block of your code into a file, run it, and reproduce your problem. This also lets us test any possible solutions in your context.